# Cascade delete in Ruby ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, database-relations

I was following the screencast on rubyonrails.org (creating the blog).

I have following models:

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    validates_presence_of :body # I added this
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :body, :title
    has_many :comments
end
```

Relations between models work fine, except for one thing - when I delete a post record, I'd expect RoR to delete all related comment records. I understand that ActiveRecords is database independent, so there's no built-in way to create foreign key, relations, ON DELETE, ON UPDATE statements. So, is there any way to accomplish this (maybe RoR itself could take care of deleting related comments? )?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes. On a Rails' model association you can specify the `:dependent` option, which can take one of the following three forms:

- `:destroy/:destroy_all` The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object by calling their `destroy` method
- `:delete/:delete_all` All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling their `:destroy` method
- `:nullify` All associated objects' foreign keys are set to `NULL` without calling their `save` callbacks

Note that the `:dependent` option is ignored if you have a `:has_many X, :through => Y` association set up.

So for your example you might choose to have a post delete all its associated comments when the post itself is deleted, without calling each comment's `destroy` method. That would look like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :body, :title
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

#### Update for Rails 4:

In Rails 4, you should use `:destroy` instead of `:destroy_all`.

If you use `:destroy_all`, you'll get the exception:

> The :dependent option must be one of [:destroy, :delete_all, :nullify,
>   :restrict_with_error, :restrict_with_exception]

Comment: Thanks! Found your answer helpful. Little remark: the :dependent option can have value of :destroy, :delete_all, or :nullify.

Comment: At least as of rails 4, :destroy_all is not an option. Use :destroy instead.

Comment: In Rails 4, you should use `:destroy` instead of `:destroy_all`
From rails logs: `The :dependent option must be one of [:destroy, :delete_all, :nullify, :restrict_with_error, :restrict_with_exception]`