# before_destroy on a relationship model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

I am using a has_many through association and having trouble getting the before_destroy call back to trigger.  I am using a Relating class to relate models.

```
class Relating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :relater, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :related, :polymorphic => true

  before_destroy :unset_reminders
end
```

For example, a user can add TvShows to a list of favorites, User.rb:

```
has_many :tv_shows, :through => :relateds, :source => :related, :source_type => 'TvShow'
```

The problem I am having, has to do with deleting this Relating record.

I can relate users and tv shows by:

```
user = User.find(1)
show = TvShow.find(1)
user.tv_shows << show
```

But when I want to remove this association, the before_destroy is not triggered by:

```
user.tv_shows.delete(show)
```

However, if I destroy the relating record manually, it does trigger the callback:

```
r = Relating.find(8012)
r.destroy
```

How can I get the before destroy to be triggered for this?

Thanks

Comment: This may help:
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896777/cascade-delete-in-ruby-activerecord-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete` method does not trigger callbacks as mentioned [in the docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete). Try `destroy` instead.

Update: I didn't realize you were trying to destroy the join record and not the show itself. I'm surprised `delete` works at all but perhaps that is a feature of `has_many :through`. How about:

```
user.relateds.where(tv_show_id: show.id).destroy
```

Comment: I tried this also...what seemed to happen was, 1. the record was not removed from the relating model, 2. the TvShow was completely removed from tv_shows...

Comment: Yes, this does work...I'm not too stoked on doing it this way, I wish I could find a way to have the before_destroy be triggered when simply doing user.tv_shows.delete(show)  I wonder why before_destroy doesn't work when doing this...Anyway, thanks Ryan!