# how to do ruby on rails relationship dependent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, relationship, dependent-destroy

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Based on the above example, I created:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Can someone guide me how can I perform a cascading delete action.

1. if I delete a Patient, I want all appointments for the patient deleted. Do I need to use **dependent** keyword somewhere ? Can someone demonstrate how to solve this.
2. How do I delete all appointments for a particular patient ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cascade delete in Ruby ActiveRecord models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896777/cascade-delete-in-ruby-activerecord-models)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

`Patient.find(id).destroy`

This should work for you. Make sure you use `destroy` and not `delete` because if you use delete you won't have the cascading effect you expect.

Update 2:

If you want to destroy all appointments but not the patient you can do this:

`Patient.find(id).appointments.destroy_all`

Comment: can you also provide the answer for: How do I delete all appointments for a particular patient ? (just the appointments, not the patient) Thanks