# SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but what I'm doing is testing the `destroy` route on my User model.

When I try and `@user.destroy`, I get the following exception:

```
*** ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey Exception: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?
```

The only problem is, I already have `dependent: :destroy` in place for the `has_many` association, and I have also tried `:delete_all` to no avail. This is the only association I have to this model right now.

Any ideas? I'm sure its something simple

Comment: Please read [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896777/cascade-delete-in-ruby-activerecord-models).  I propose that your setup has a problem such that the `dependent` option is not working.

Comment: Does not seem to be the case, I do not have a `through` dependency

Comment: Do you have another object created in your test that references the user?  I just ran into a similar issue when I didn't have my relationships ordered properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check your schema to see if you have other relations in your model, if you have more relations use the `dependent: :destroy`, also showing the schema to see the relations would help to see if other models have a relation with your model.